# Why I'm getting different results when I'm using whereRaw and where in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I was working on the php laravel. I'm just trying to write a query to pull the records by joining two tables. It is working fine when I'm using whereRaw, but not working with where. Can any one help me with this?

**whereRaw**

```
$productsBuyer = DB::table('clearing_quantity_products')
                            ->join('products', 'clearing_quantity_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id' )
                            ->whereRaw('clearing_quantity_products.available > products.pallet_qty')
                            ->get();
```

**where**

```
$productsBuyer = DB::table('clearing_quantity_products')
                            ->join('products', 'clearing_quantity_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id' )
                            ->where('clearing_quantity_products.available','>', 'products.pallet_qty' ) 
                            ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried to compare the SQL queries that are executed on both the queries?

Comment: the `where` method is for comparing a column to a value, not comparing 2 columns ... so you are using the call to `where` wrong (need to use a different method to compare 2 columns) .. the `whereRaw` is comparing 2 columns

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea what are the other different methods to compare two columns other than whereRaw

Comment: You can also do `->where('clearing_quantity_products.available','>', DB::raw(''products.pallet_qty'))`, but there is also `whereColumn` which may be best in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `where` method of Query Builder is for comparing a column to a value, not a column to another column. For that you would need to use something like `whereColumn`:

```
->whereColumn('clearing_quantity_products.available', '>', 'products.pallet_qty')
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Query Builder - Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) - `whereColumn`